# NGINX behind Apache force $host variable from Apache

Tags: nginx, apache2

**My setup looks as following**

```
example.com -> apache2 (proxy) -> NGINX (proxy) -> uwsgi (Djagno)
```

**Apache takes care of https and passing requests to NGINX like:**

```
<VirtualHost example.com:443>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com

   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:7995/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:7995/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**NGINX is listening on port 7995 and passing requests to uwsgi (Djagno)**

```
location / {

    set $upstream django:8000;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials false;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Origin, User-Agent";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS";

    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;
    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_set_header            Host $host; <-- I do need example.com here but it is 128.0.0.1
    proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_hide_header           X-Frame-Options;

    proxy_pass http://$upstream;

    ...
}
```

**My problem is:** `$host` in NGINX config will always be `127.0.0.1`. (which gives some troubles with Django)

**My question is:** I do not want to change NGINX conf if possible. What can to be set on side of Apache (host header?) that NGINX sets `$host` as `example.com`?

Comment: Try `ProxyPreserveHost on` in the Apache configuration.

Comment: thanks Ivan I've tried `RequestHeader set Host "example.com"
    ProxyPreserveHost On` but unfortuantely this is ending an in infinite loop :/ I guess because ProxyPass is pointing to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you sure that redirect does no come from the django upstream? You can check it defining your own log format and logging the `$http_host` (`Host` header value passed to the django) and `$upstream_http_location` variable values.

Comment: Thanks Ivan stupid misstake, the redirect came from my local /etc/hosts file. After playing around with the apache vhost conf I decided to take the short way and set the header on side of nginx. Doing so Django gets the correct host and my problems  are solved. Thanks for your help ;)